# InputFields not working updating properly when in a CDF

Tags: dynamic, cdf-format, inputfield

I have made a calculator and embedded it on my website. It consists of several InputField boxes for inputting equations (x, x^2, 1+x ...). It functions as the notebook does except when the input gets more complicated than a single variable the InputField does not update.

For example in the CDF player if you type in "x" and press enter the results update as expected. If you now type "x^2" and press enter the results do not update but in the notebook it would have updated properly.

I can link to the website if needed.

You can preview this toy model in the CDF player for the same results.

```
startingarray = IdentityMatrix[4];
Manipulate[
size = i;
it = Table[With[{i = i, j = j},InputField[Dynamic[startingarray[[i, j]]], Expression, FieldSize -> 5,]], {i,size}, {j, size}];
Dynamic[{TableForm[it],TableForm[startingarray[[1 ;; i, 1 ;; i]]]}, 1],{{i, 4, "Dimension"}, 2, 4, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that a CDF `InputField` will only accept numeric input and not text (or symbols such as `x^2`).  That's one of the restrictions when using CDF.

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html